# Mongoose.js: Find all users who liked Cat post

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schema models.

```
const catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: 'string',
  likes: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'User',
      require: true
    }
  ],
});
```

and

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
});
```

Let's say there are 10 Cat documents in Cat collection.
And one user liked two of the Cat docs.
What I want to do is that I want to find the two cat lists which the user liked through Cat model.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below, let me know if it helps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$in` query from MongoDB to achieve this. 
Detailed Info here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

**From the docs:** 
The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

I used it once to get Groups, where the user is member of. In your case you should be successful with the following :

```js
const Cat = require('./models/Cat');
Cat.find({ likes : { $in : [user] }}).exec((cats) => {
  console.log(cats);
});

// user in this case should be the user document
// the query checks if the user is included in the 'likes' arrady
```